# Blocking ONLY spaces from being entered into a from textfield

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textfield in which users have to enter their name. The problem I'm having is stopping the users from only entering spaces. I want users to be able to use spaces but only if they have other characters (abc, ABC, 1-9, etc.). How can I stop them from only entering spaces? And can this be done onkeyup or onkeypress?

Comment: i hope my code is working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like below it will restrict white space at the starting

```
  ​$("#textareaid").on("keydown", function (e) {
  var len = $("#textareaid").val().length;
  if(len == 0)
      return e.which !== 32;
  });​​​​​
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8o6h6x01/)**

**UPDATE**

There is some limitation in above method, that is when user enter some characters in textarea and then move cursor to zeroth position of text area then try to enter a space then it will allow. the below solution overcomes that too ..

**html**

```
<textarea id="text1"></textarea>
```

**javascript**

```
   $("#text1").on("keydown", function (e) {
    var len = $("#text1").val().length;
    if(len == 0)
    {
        return e.which !== 32;
    }
    else 
    {
      var pos=$("#text1").getCursorPosition();
         if(pos==0)
       {


           return e.which !== 32;

       }

    }

});

$("#text1").on("keyup", function (e) {
var pos=$("#text1").getCursorPosition();
       if(pos==0)
       {

           var values =$("#text1").val();
            if(values.charAt(0)==' ')
            {
                values=values.trim();
                $("#text1").val(values);
            }
           return e.which !== 32;

       }
});

(function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

working example of above code [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b8s678b1/2/)